# Facebook api authorization in IE

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I have a problem with facebook authorization in Internet Explorer. 
This code works in Firefox, chrome and safari, but not in IE.

After clicking on href with loginUrl this message appears (only in IE otherwise is all good).

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be
>   used to query information about the current user. thrown in
>   /data/web/virtuals/30096/virtual/www/qcomp/libs/base_facebook.php on
>   line 1238

Here is my code:

`session_start();

    define('APP_ID', 'SOMETHING');
    define('APP_SECRET', 'SOMETHING');
    define('CANVAS_PAGE', 'SOMETHING');
    define('CANVAS_URL', 'SOMETHING');

    require_once './libs/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_SECRET, ));

   $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $redirecturl = 'BACK_TO_TAB';

    if(isset($user)) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user_profile;
            $_SESSION['friends'] = $user_friends;
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

        $user = NULL;
      }
}

if($user == NULL)
{ 
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope' => 'publish_stream',
            'redirect_uri' => 'URL',
        )
    );
}
else
{   
    header("Location: ./step2.php");
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user_profile;
    $_SESSION['friends'] = $user_friends;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="layout">
            <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl ?>" target="_blank">
                <div class="enter"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: Perchance this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10724908/1195891) with accepted answer is what applies to you. Keep in mind the solution to look for is to enable 3rd party cookies.

Comment: Glad to help. Will vote to close this question. Consider Upvoting that SO Answer as well. Cheers!