# Auto login facebook - FB.Event.subscribe auth.login doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

for some reason today my code for auto login for existed members broke.
normally this code works perfect, after a check with firebug I saw that there is a problem finding 'auth.login' for some reason, and therefor the call for window.location.reload(); isn't working. (if I refresh manually then the member shows as connect properly,the problem is just the auto login before the session is open that need a page refresh)
I also tried to see if the problem is only 'auto.login' and replaced it with 'auth.authResponseChange' when I did it the page kept on refreshing ... so I figure that problem is with 'auth.login' trigger.
does anyone knows for a special reason or any change facebook made that could cause this problem?

****update**** BUG is solved! this problem was fixed by facebook.

this bug was reported and also answered by facebook here-

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/524245490930206?browse=search_50f87d9e8869a5e06191882#

BTW,Here is A WORKING AGAIN code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
              appId  : '<?php =$APP_ID ?>',
              status : true, // check login status
              cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
              oauth  : true
        });

      // Additional initialization code here
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems i'm experiencing the same problem ..

Till a few hours ago, when a user (who had already authorized and logged in to my app previously) opened my website and the cookie was expired, the login button appeared but after a few seconds (the time for the JS SDK to trigger the login function), he was automatically logged-in and the page was reloaded without the login button and with the user information.

Now when an already registered user opens my site after cookie expired, the login button appears again, but the user isn't automatically logged in and the page doesn't reload like it did before. The strange thing is that if i click on the login button it doesn't work either! If i now refresh the page manually the login button disappears and user information is displayed, so it seems that the user was actually logged-in but the event was not caught to trigger the page reload.

If i manually log-out and login again (thus using the php sdk) everything works.

My code:

```
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
                });
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
        function facebookLogin() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                // handle the response
            }, {scope: 'email, publish_stream, read_friendlists'});
        }
    </script>
```

**UPDATE** I added this few lines to my js code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
                alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
            });
```

So now when the users opens my page after token expired:

- the php sdk detects he's not logged in and displays the login dialog
  (like before)
- the javascript sdk triggers the login functions (like
  before)
- the user gets regularly logged (in like before) (i can know
  it for sure now because it pops up the alert: The status of the
  session is:connected)
- BUT.. the event auth.login is not triggered ->
  the script isn't aware of succeeded log in ->  the page is not
  reloaded

Comment: Thank you for the info, the bug reported on facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/524245490930206?browse=search_50f87d9e8869a5e06191882

Comment: I opened the bug since i have experience of facebook team resolving issues quickly. The developer who's carrying the bug wrote to me further questions and seems to be going deeply into the problem. Hope everything would be fixed soon!

Comment: From what I understood they fixed a bug and this will not change, as he wrote:  "We fixed a previous bug where auth.login would be fired on each page load instead of only when the status goes from unknown to connected, ie. the user signing into Facebook while using your app. The auth.statusChange and auth.authResponseChange events still fire as before and you should be able to modify your code accordingly." so basically he suggest to solve this problem like Breez solution here ...am I missing something?

Comment: Actually yes. Don't know if you can see the replies but he also wrote:
"Is it correct to assume that if you set `status: true`, this starts working again?"

Which, obviously, doesn't work! so I think that when they fixed the bug they were not meant to affect the auth.login behavior the way they did. Maybe they just caused an unexpected collateral issue. Also i don't even know if the problem is related to the bug they fixed or not. 
My code should work causeit means to reload the page only when the user successfully logs in (and not on each page load), but at the current state, it doesn't work!

Comment: `auth.statusChange` does not get triggered if the user is already logged in + authorized. I had to subscribe to `auth.authResponseChange` for the event to be triggered.

Answer (score 3):

I changed from auth.login to auth.statusChange, and also wrapped everything in getLoginStatus, so it runs only when it is not connected, it seems to be working ok. Looks like this (inside window.fbAsyncInit = function() {)

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status != 'connected') {
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          // whatever code runs when user logs in
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Nice, I guess this doesn't need the PHP sdk check that Marco Gagliardi suggested in his answer, because you do the check for connected users with JAVA sdk. if I get it right.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I was having the infinite loop of refreshing until I wrapped it in getLoginStatus

Comment: Nice tip - was having this issue until I found this.

Comment: It's a great solution to avoid infinite loop in Internet Explorer.

Comment: In this thread is another solution wich helps. I think the infinite loop is caused by wrong cookies...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724908/facebook-authentication-in-ie-not-woking

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. The javascript SDK made the users auto-login with a page reload if they connected my app and their access token had expired.

I solved it by switching to auth.statusChange instead of auth.login.
Then I check with the PHP Facebook SDK if the user is logged in and if he is, i don't subscribe to the auth.statusChange event in javascript. (If you do include the auth.statusChange in javascript when the user is logged in, you will end up in an infinite page refresh loop, at least that was the case with my implementation).

Comment: This can work... great original way but that's like a back door ... I looked at the facebook original page for FB.event.subscribe and nothing new there...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
if this won't be fixed in the next couple of days I will use and approve your solution thank you very much.

Comment: a bug openned on that subject -
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/524245490930206?browse=search_50f87d9e8869a5e06191882

Comment: as you can see one of faceboook team wrote - 
"We fixed a previous bug where `auth.login` would be fired on each page load instead of only when the status goes from `unknown` to `connected`, ie. the user signing into Facebook while using your app.
The `auth.statusChange` and `auth.authResponseChange` events still fire as before and you should be able to modify your code accordingly."

Comment: Well, it seems to me they tried to fix a bug but yet introduced a new bug... I am going to keep using my fix anyway. In fact, it's a good solution since it scraps some superfluous code if the user is connected